# SED regex find (and remove) option from a command text

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a config file with param=option[,option...], using standard `bash` utilities, perhaps the the help of **`sed`**, remove one option from the list.

```
     #
     param=aa,bb,cc
     param=aa,bb
     param=bb,cc
     param=bb
     #
```

in this example, I want to remove **'bb'** (and the separator) from all lines, and in the last case, because **'bb'** was the sole option, remove the complete line, so the final result will be

```
     #
     param=aa,cc
     param=aa
     param=cc
     #
```

option **'bb'** can be alone or at the start, center or end of the list. Obviously, 'bb' embedded on another option name (ie xxbb, bbxx, etc) should not be considered.

edit: fix typo, addn'l example

Comment: Nice Problem. Do you need to edit it inline (`sed -i`)? Or can it be piped to an output file using `grep` to remove some lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `sed` version to remove `bb` parameter from any position and delete the line if `bb` is the only parameter:

First the input file:

```
#
param=aa,bb,cc
param=aa,bb
param=bb,cc
param=bb
#
```

Now run this `sed`:

```
sed -E '/^param=/{/=bb$/d; s/,bb(,|$)/\1/; s/=bb,/=/;}' file
```

This will give:

```
#
param=aa,cc
param=aa
param=cc
#
```

To use inline editing use:

```
sed -i.bak -E '/^param=/{/=bb$/d; s/,bb(,|$)/\1/; s/=bb,/=/;}' file
```

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. I compared your output with the expected question output.  I will delete the comment. sorry again

Comment: No problems at all. I added a new line in input to cover for another case not shown in OP's input.

Comment: We can use `sed -E '/^param=/{/=bb$/d; s/,bb(,|$)/\1/; s/=bb,/=/;}' file` is this is to be done for only `param=` config lines.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: The solutions below do not address *updating* the input file; a simple (though not fully robust) approach is to use

`awk '...' file > file.$$ && mv file.$$ file`</sup>

A POSIX-compliant `awk` solution that should work robustly:

```
awk -F'=' '
  $1 != "param" { print; next }
  {
    sub(/,bb,/, ",", $2)
    sub(/(^|,)bb$/, "", $2)
    if ($2 != "") print $1 FS $2
  }
' file
```

*GNU* `awk` allows for a simpler solution, using its (nonstandard) `gensub()` function:

```
awk -F'=' '
  $1 != "param" { print; next }
  {
    newList = gensub(/(^|,)bb(,|$)/, "\\2", 1, $2)
    if (newList != "") print $1 FS newList
  }
' file
```

A (POSIX-compliant) field-based alternative (more verbose, but perhaps easier to generalize):

```
awk -F'=' '
  $1 != "param" { print; next }
  {
    n = split($2, opts, ","); optList = ""
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
      if (opts[i] != "bb") {
        optList = optList (optList == "" ? "" : ",") opts[i]
      }
    }
    if (optList != "") print $1 FS optList
  }
' file
```

Comment: `awk` is very weird sometimes. Need to dig in it little more. Looks powerful but when I see this, I want to ask why not write a script ?

Comment: @JazZ: Yes, it's a little verbose; see my update, which adds a simpler, regex-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a temporary format to be able to find the occurrences easier. And to remove lines I would suggest using `grep`:

```
sed 's/=/=,/;s/$/,/;s/,bb,/,/;s/=,/=/;s/,$//;/=$/d'
```

the `s/=/=,/` converts it to:

```
param=,aa,bb,cc
param=,aa,bb
param=,bb
```

than `s/$/,/` to:

```
param=,aa,bb,cc,
param=,aa,bb,
param=,bb,
```

than `s/,bb,/,/`

```
param=,aa,cc,
param=,aa,
param=,
```

and `s/=,/=/;s/,$//` will remove the commata at the begining and end again

removing empty options can be done with `grep -v '=$'`, or some more advanced sed magic (so it can be still used with `sed -i`)

*EDIT:*
the "sed magic" is just appending '/=$/d'

tested this one, and it works fine:

```
sed -i 's/=/=,/;s/$/,/;s/,bb,/,/;s/=,/=/;s/,$//;/=$/d' filename
```

or

```
sed 's/=/=,/;s/$/,/;s/,bb,/,/;s/=,/=/;s/,$//;/=$/d' filename_in > filename_out
```

Comment: I think OP doesn't want the line itself when bb is only present after =, which is not taken care in above code

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Read the last line. The `param=` can be removed by `grep -v '=$'`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your Input_file is as follows:

```
param=aa,bb,cc
param=aa,bb
param=bb
```

Then the following code:

```
awk -F"=" '$2=="bb"{next} {sub(/,bb/,"");print}'  Input_file
```

outputs:

```
param=aa,cc
param=aa
```

Comment: It's elegant and works with the sample input, but you'll get false positives if a line contains `,bb1`, for instance.

Comment: i think this won't work for `param=bb,cc`. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: this should work: `sub(/,bb,/,",");sub(/=bb,/,"=");sub(/,bb$/,"");` instead of `sub(/,bb/,"")`